# Player rotation and camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want the player to look into the direction, the camera is looking.

The camera follows the player (3rd person game style).

I've tried it with

```
transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(transform.localRotation.x,
  cameraMain.transform.localRotation.y, 
  transform.localRotation.z, 
  transform.localRotation.w);
```

but it doesn't work.

Sometimes the player starts rotating the other direction.

Comment: What is the player's `transform.localScale`?

Comment: x/y/z is 1/1/1  .

Comment: What happens when you use `transform.rotation = cameraMain.transform.rotation` ?

Comment: then the player gets the x and z rotation of the camera, too and starts rotating around and through the ground.

Answer (score 1):

the following code will make the object (specified in the parameter) face in the direction of where the main camera is looking:

```
public void lookInDirectionOfCamera(Transform object) {
   RayCastHit hit;
   if (Physics.raycast(cameraMain.transform.position, cameraMain.transform.forward, out hit)) {
      object.forward = hit.point - object.position;
   }else { //if the raycast didnt hit anything, make the object face 100 units in front of the camera
      Vector3 point = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 100;
      object.forward = point - object.position;
   }
}
```

This will make the player face the point that is forward to the camera. If you just want them to have the same rotation in the y-axis don't use Quaternions!
Instead, you can just do it with Euler angles:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x,
cameraMain.transform.eulerAngles.y,
transform.eulerAngles.y);
```

The reason not to use transform.localRotation is because that is a Quaternion. The y component in a Quaternion is not the same as the y-axis in a Euler angle (what you are used to seeing), Quaternions are very confusing so you should almost never set individual values in them. If you want to edit them only use the built-in methods.

Comment: do note that I haven't tried this code, so if it doesn't work please tell me so I can update the post!

Comment: it should be `transform.eulerAngles`

Answer (score 0):

Get the direction the camera is looking with `cameraMain.transform.forward`, make a copy with a y value of zero, then use `Quaternion.SetLookRotation` to look in that direction with the global up direction.:

```
Vector3 cameraDirection = cameraMain.transform.forward;
Vector3 characterLookDirection = new Vector3(cameraDirection.x,
                                             0f,
                                             cameraDirection.z);
Quaternion newRotation = new Quaternion();
newRotation.SetLookRotation(characterLookDirection, Vector3.up); 
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

Comment: @AlpakaJoe I realized I made a mistake a few moments ago, so I edited it. This should work.